# Why are project files in Altium modified every time they are opened? Is there a way to prevent this?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, design, altium, cad

I use Altium Designer 18. When I open a project file (.PrjPCB), the asterisk ("*") appears next to the project name indicating that the project has been modified, but I haven't actually made any changes.

I've been using Altium for years, and I've always wondered about this. I'd really like to change this if possible, because I sometimes worry that I've somehow accidentally made changes to the project that I didn't intend.

EDIT: I'm aware that in some cases, Altium can't find the library files that are linked to the project and removes those from the project. This is not what's happening in this case. Often, when I open a project, and *no library files are removed from the project*, the project is still modified and (even if I don't make any changes), I'm asked if I want to save changes to the project when I close Altium.

Also am not making changes to any of the project files (.SchDoc files, .PcbDoc files, etc).

Comment: AFAIK Altium can very well integrate with many popular source control systems. That would be the best way to ensure you are not changing stuff accidentally.

Comment: If Altium is unable to find certain files (such as library files) on startup it will come up with a window saying `xxxx.xxx could not be found and will be removed from the project.` Are you getting any of these messages? If so, when the file is removed it modifies the project so it recognizes it as a change.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for your reply. I'm aware that Altium integrates with SVN and CVS. Is this what you're talking about?

Comment: @DerStrom8 Thanks for your reply.

I'm aware that if Altium can't find the library files that are associated with the project, the library files (and any other files that Altium can't find) will be removed from the project and that is certainly a change to the project file, this isn't what's happening. There are no files being removed from the project when I open it and Altium still seems to think that there are changes to the project that it needs to prompt me to ask if I want the changes saved.

Comment: @Danny Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: @Danny.  Yes, I see this exact same behavior using AD 15.1.16.  Wish I could help.  Because I am the only one to touch my designs I ignore this (false) indication of an edit.

Comment: This behavior is still true for AD20, and it also bothers me.  I have used diff to compare the files (which are plain text) and it is usually something minor, but if you don't check how would you know?

Comment: Same problem. Tech support knows nothing but keeps telling me to install the latest version. What a joke, the latest version is always full of bugs...

Answer (score 1):

It might be saving your project state (i.e. previous view/zoom and currently opened files in your project). I know several programs that do this including schematic capture, PCB layout, mechanical CAD, IDEs, and even spreadsheet software that liked to save which cells you were looking at and which cell your selector was on.

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me slightly nuts for a min, and I had some projects that would be "modified" as soon as Altium opened it and others which would behave fine.

I dug through the project parameters looking to see what was different.

I found something that fixed this problem for me, hopefully it helps you too. If you go into your Project Options, go to the 'Options' tab. There is a section for "Net Identifier Scope". When this was set to "Automatic", I had the issue with Altium falsely thinking I had modified the project file. When I changed this to either "Flat" or "Hierarchical", the issue went away.